# Show that for any real matrix $A$, $||A||_2=\sup_{x\ne0, y\ne 0}\frac{|y^TAx|}{||y||_2||x||_2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Show that for any real matrix $A$, $$||A||_2=\sup_{x\ne0, y\ne 0}\frac{|y^TAx|}{||y||_2||x||_2}$$

Here i only know that $||A\|_2=\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$

can some one suggest me book of where i get metrics on matrices and norm on the matrices

thank you so much....

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy.. i edited now sir...

Comment: Welcome to the site. We look for posts that have more than just a problem - please see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more info. The information that is missing here includes the source and motivation of the question, along with any attempts you have made. For example, in this post you have not indicated whether you even know the identity is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RHS $\leq $ is easy. [Use: $|u^{T}v| \leq \|u\|\|v\|$]. For the other way take $y=Ax$. [Use: $|(Ax)^{T} Ax|=\|Ax\|^{2}$].

Comment: ...how RHS is easy coz we using sup definition?

Comment: @InverseProblem $|y^{T}Ax| \leq \|y\| \|Ax\| \leq \|y\| \|x\| \|A\|$ and this gives RHS $\leq $ LHS.